# Scrolling select element not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, materialize

I'm using google's materializecss framework for rendering some `select` elements (http://materializecss.com/forms.html). The `select` element is rendered with `ul` elements in the framework. When I apply a scroll bar to the `ul` with `css`, the `ul` disappears when user tries to scroll with mouse (works with the scroll wheel). This happens only in chrome (tested with chrome 42) [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/49rzqgwn/2/)

Anybody knows a solution for this? Thanks in advance...

Comment: The problem is that you are styling `ul` not the `options` of `select`

Comment: @Amitsingh Can I control the *height* of the `ul` by styling the `options`?